# Problem - I cant run the program with Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2019

I have problem when i click on the "Start" button.

When i click on the Start button, the google chrome window opens but an error appears.
I installed google chrome latest version as well as visual studio, selenium webdriver and chrome driver.

I expected it to automatically open the Google Chrome window and enter the text in the search tab.

```cs
namespace Sel
{
    class Program
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        static void Main(string[] args) { }
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("facebook.com");
        }
        [Test]
        public void ExecuteTest
        {
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
      IWebElement searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
        searchBox.SendKeys("jdaj@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code snippet to get you the help, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the error?